# Is there a way to use the authoryear with the number of reference at the same time in latex

Tags: natbib

I would like to have References of my report to be presented as follows:

in  text:

(Goossens et al., 1993)[1].

I used a natbib. And the bibliographstyle  is `plainnat`. (mac user) I am using Texmaker.

Can that be possible in latex? if yes, how can I do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: @Johannes_B  could you please show me how?

Comment: you have tagged this biblatex but you have shown no example document: are you using biblatex/biber or bibtex ?

Comment: I correct the tag. Sorry.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily modify your citation style with natbib:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand\cite[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})[\citenum{#1}]}
```

Then

```
\cite{latex}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{harvard}
```

will produce:
[image]

Comment: Although this works, it's not a good idea to redefine an internal command (unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing). Rather, I would create a variant of the command with a different name, like `\Cite`.